# Is it possible to ignore some files while running lerna watch?

Tags: lerna

I am developing a monorepo. Each package has a build command which compiles the code and outputs it to its ./dist folder.

The problem I'm facing is that when I run lerna watch, it comes into a loop. Each build triggers a new build and so on.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior and only run build when some source code has changed, ignoring the ./dist/**/* files?

Answer (score 2):

## Use .nxignore file

In your root folder create `.nxignore` file add your **build** folder using the same syntax as a [`.gitignore` files](https://nx.dev/reference/nxignore#.nxignore)

```
packages/my-package-name/dist/
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite)

With [Lerna-Lite Watch](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite/tree/main/packages/watch#readme), which I maintain, you can provide files/folders to ignore since all [Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) options are available to Lerna-Lite Watch command.

Note that `.git`, `dist` and `node_modules` are automatically ignored in Lerna-Lite watch (as you can see on this [line](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite/blob/main/packages/watch/src/watch-command.ts#L84) in the code implementation)

```bash
# ignore bin folder
$ lerna watch --ignored=\"**/bin\" -- <command>

# ignore dot file
$ lerna watch --ignored=\"/(^|[/\\])\../\" -- <command>
```

or via the Glob option

```bash
# glob pattern will be appended to package path that Chokidar watches
$ lerna watch --glob=\"src\**\*.ts" -- <command>
```

#### [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) (original)

For the original Lerna, I'm not exactly sure if you can ignore files/folders because their implementation is very different and came from their new Nx Watch command. They created their own file watcher daemon, which behind the scene uses `@parcel/watcher`, and I'm not sure if any of the ignore options are available externally to the developers. A quick glance at the code and I don't see any ignore options available. Also taking a look at both [Lerna Watch docs](https://lerna.js.org/docs/features/workspace-watching) and [Nx Watch docs](https://nx.dev/recipes/other/workspace-watching), it doesn't look like any of them have anything available to ignore files, so we can only guess that it's not possible at the moment!?

##### Summary

So in short, I can't verify if this is doable on the original Lerna side... but you can definitely ignore files/folders in [Lerna-Lite Watch](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite/tree/main/packages/watch#readme). Also note that the watch command usage is very similar in both Lerna and Lerna-Lite but their implementation (internally) are entirely different.

Comment: Excelente, thank you for your answer. Another question, Lerna-Lite Watch replaces lerna or works in parallel with it?

Comment: I created Lerna-Lite when Lerna was not maintained for over a year and couple months before Nrwl took over Lerna. At the time, I wanted to update dependencies to fix some security issues, Lerna-Lite is also more modular than Lerna since you can choose which command to install and lastly Lerna-Lite does not use Nx at all but the new Lerna requires Nx since it's now maintained by Nrwl. You can see more info on main [readme](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite#about-lerna-lite), the old Lerna commands are the same code implementation but new commands like `watch` could be different.

Comment: I wasn't sure about your question but if your question was more about `lerna watch` itself, then I would say that you would use lerna watch when you want to watch the entire workspace in a single watch and you want to know which package changed so that you can trigger a build. You could also add `--include-dependents` to build also its dependent(s), you would not be able to do anything similar with other libraries watch because other libraries would probably not know the full workspace graph. in my use case I had multiple `tsc` watch and replaced it with one lerna watch which is less consuming